# Android: Detecting USB

Tags: android, usb

Is there any way to know(programmatically) in your Activity/Application that the user has connected your phone to PC through USB?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Some people suggested using `UMS_CONNECTED` which is deprecated as of recent version of Android
The other problem with that is that it does not work with MTP enabled devices

Others suggested the use of the `BatteryManager`, more precisely `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` as well as `BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC` and `BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB`
This is perfect if you want to detect the Battery or Charging status of the device, but is not a really good indicator of a USB connection.
Using the battery manager is prone to failure on older android tablets such as the XOOM, the ICONIA tab A510, and the older Asus tablets.

To purely detect that the device was plugged on a PC you can:
Use `android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE` and `connected`
in place of the `BatteryManager` stuff

Code sample

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE"));
        return intent.getExtras().getBoolean("connected");
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Unclear from the documentation what this is actually detecting.  In my case I am trying to diagnose a faulty USB cable, where sometimes the power state does not change but USB drops in and out - the latter is what I am trying to detect.

Answer (score 6):

Was able to detect USB connection by registering a broadcast receiver by following,

```
IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED);

BroadcastReceiver bd = new intentReceiver();
registerReceiver(bd, mIntentFilter);
```

Comment: It doesn't work if the device is using MTP protocole instead of the UMS one (for example the Galaxy Nexus is using the MTP protocol)

Comment: @darkheir Thanks for pointing this one out. Will update the answer once I find a generalized solution.

Comment: @Fresh_Meat in the following topic i'm suggesting a solution working for both MTP and UMS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182986/android-honeycomb-3-2-detect-mtp-connection-via-usb/11574908#11574908
The idea is to check the battery state, cheking also if the Smartphone was connected in USB or AC

Comment: @Fresh_Meat Really nice of you :-)

Answer (score 6):

This works for me.

Add this on your AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <receiver android:name=".PlugInControlReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And Create your `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
public class PlugInControlReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.v("PlugInControlReceiver","action: "+action);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

            if(action.equals("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE")) {

                if(intent.getExtras().getBoolean("connected")){

                    Toast.makeText(context, "USB Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{

                    Toast.makeText(context, "USB Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } else {
            if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "USB Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "USB Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }  
   }      
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Manifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ums_connected" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

MyReceiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(
        "android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED")) {...}
}
```

Comment: This MyReceiver code doesn't even have sense.. an if inside the class definition?

Answer (score 5):

If all you want to do is detect whether you have access to the sdcard, then the following will work:

```
private boolean canWriteToFlash() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        // Read only isn't good enough
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The main problem while checking `android.intent.action.ums_connected` is that devices using the MTP protocol (such as the Samsung Nexus Galaxy) don't receive this broadcast.

This is why I'm using another way to detect when the Smartphone is plugged or unplugged:

I check the batery state. There is an intent called `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` called when an event happens on the battery. In this intent there are some extra fields containing some informations. One of them is `EXTRA_PLUGGED`:

```
Indicating whether the device is plugged in to a power source; 0 means it is on battery, other constants are different types of power sources.
```

The other constants are `BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC` and `BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB`

So with this broadcast you can know if the Smartphone has been plugged in USB even if it uses the MTP protocol.

To know if the Smartphone is unplugged you juste have to check when the `EXTRA_PLUGGED` value changes from `BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB` to `0`

Comment: This doesn't work for tablets like XOOM, where power and usb are two different ports

Comment: I didn't test it, but maybe you could to verify it by checking if it is a `BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB` or `BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC`.