# android: detecting usb mass storage mode

Tags: android, usb, storage

I have a very simple question. When a device like (galaxy tab) is connected to a computer in mass storage mode; both internal and external sd-card become unavailable. I just want to know if there is any way of determining if internal storage is not available because the device is in usb mass storage mode..

Thanks to all

Comment: You have to use a PendingIntent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600896/android-detecting-usb

Comment: are you wanting to check at a specific point in your application, or be notified when the status of the storage changes? its not clear.

Answer (score 0):

For API version 8, I think the following will work.

Use a broadcast receiver that listens to [ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED)

For versions beyond 8, use android.os.storage.EventListener. Check [this](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/2.3/android/os/storage/StorageEventListener.html) out.