# Register application to launch when USB item is connected to PC

Tags: android, usb

I created an Android application I would like to automatically open when USB item running Android gets connected to the PC.

Is it possible to register my application to handle USB connection? How do I do that?

Comment: see the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600896/android-detecting-usb

Comment: hey mark,ur link is only for messaging that usb is connected or disconnected but I want to open my application after connected

Comment: respond to the message by launching your activity...

Answer (score 4):

You can listen for the [`Intent.ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED) *(usb mass storage mode started)* or [`Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED) *(the phone is charging now)* broadcasts with a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Note that both do not exactly tell you that you are connected to a computer. The charge broadcast might be as well fired when a normal charger is connected. The USB broadcast is a good indicator that you have something like a pc on the other end of the wire, but it's no guarantee. The user can also just connect the phone to the computer without entering mass storage mode.

*As far as I know* there is no intent that tells you for sure that you are connected to a computer *(I can see that it's hard to detect without an application on the pc)*. You may want to read the [intent class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and see if you can find a broadcast that I didn't see yet.

Comment: ya I have used this code Before but it is only detected the USB Connection..but How can I see My App.

Comment: Launch an `Intent` from the `BroadcastReceivers` `onReceive()` method.

Answer (score 4):

In your Manifest.xml, add this:

```
<receiver android:name=".BattStatusShow">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ums_connected" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then have your battery status class extend `BroadcastReceiver`, since your registered it for USB messages in the Manifest file.

```
public class BattStatusShow extends BroadcastReceiver{ 
  if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase( "android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED")) {
    //do stuff here, like signal the view of your app it needs to do something
  }
}
```

You don't give much information about what your application, but if it is only a battery display application, programming a PC host application to talk to your Android app seems overkill. If you want to do more, look at how the Nokia PC station app interacts with Nokia and emulate the behavior.

Comment: but this will show thwe meassage only.How can I see this animated tomcat who says that "YOUR battery Status is ..%" Its Audio application.

Comment: You need to replace the "do stuff here" line with a line firing up an Intent to the main Activity of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can open any application from your mobile even if it is connected to PC via USB.

Visit the below link know about detecting USB connected or detached and Register a Broadcast Receiver for the same and launch your application from the Receiver using appropriate intent.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/accessory.html

Comment: I think he means *automatically* (i.e., open application *triggered* by connecting the cable)

Comment: He's asking for the application to open automatically.

Comment: yaa U r right.its means my app directly open when it is connected to the cable

Comment: yaa mark..Actually I have created an application which shows the battery status.so I want to directly open it when USB Connected to PC

Comment: He wants to register a handle for USB connection to the PC with the phone. I would not let my Android tolerate that, even if it is possible. Talk about intrusive :/ Satya, if you are connected to the PC, you are charging the phone anyway :D

Comment: yaa u r right..Kheldar..but In my application there is a animated tom cat who says the battery status so I want to open it directly

Comment: Hah, OK, I second animated tomcats :D