# how to detect usb devices connected to Android phone

Tags: android, usb, hardware

possible duplicate question. I just want to detect USB connected and get information which device connected to Android phone. I followed lots of tutorials but no luck. Also, i followed [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) as well. 
Thank youin Advance.

Comment: yes it is a duplicate..[http://stackoverflow.com/a/7301547/2310673](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7301547/2310673)

Comment: hello  bakriOnFire, Thank you for replying, but how to get USB device information which is connected to Android phone.

Comment: what all usb devices do you want to check?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Detecting USB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600896/android-detecting-usb)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Eclipse go to DDMS there you see youre device

Comment: Hello Vadym, I want to detect which USB device connected to Android phone.