# How to turn off USB mass storage programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, usb-mass-storage

I want to turn on/off the USB mass storage in Android.

I tried the below code. It's not working. Can any one please help me in this?

To disable the Mass storage I have used this:

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(getcontentResolver(),Settings.Secure_MASS_STORAGE_ENABLED,0)
```

To enable the Mass storage I have used this:

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(getcontentResolver(),Settings.Secure_MASS_STORAGE_ENABLED,1)
```

The code above is not working though. Am I need to pass any intent for this?

Comment: check this link [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396757/programmatically-turn-off-usb-storage-on-android-devices

Answer (score 2):

First, you can't modify `Settings.Secure.MASS_STORAGE_ENABLED` even you have claimed `WRITE_SETTINGS` and `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, because `Settings.Secure.*` only can be modified by apps in `system/app`, of course, read operation has not limits.

Second, I have searched the whole source code(both Gingerbread and ICS) and found that `Settings.Secure.MASS_STORAGE_ENABLED` has not been used currently, I am confused since `Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED` is used. please Google tell me why? will be implemented in next release?

Third, You can force to turn off usb mass storage connection by calling:

```
MountService.setUsbMassStorageEnabled(false);
```

or

```
StorageManager.disableUsbMassStorage();
```

but unfortunately, both these API are not public accessible?!

Comment: can any one tell me, how to use these methods.

Comment: Using reflaction