# Prevent USB port usage programmatically

Tags: android, usb

How can I programmatically prevent a user from using the USB port of an Android tablet?

I don't think it can be achieved by normal applications. Can it be done with a system application?

Can somebody suggest a good starting point.

Comment: Check this SO question, it may helps you a bit: [Programmatically Turn Off USB Storage on Android Devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396757/programmatically-turn-off-usb-storage-on-android-devices)

Comment: This thread may be helpful to you: [Stop USB Port programmatically](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/131d7638634f8812?pli=1)

Comment: @Paresh Mayani Later one suggest to build a kernel module and moving the driver to/fro for enable/disabling usb storage! Is that you suggesting? Do I need to write my own kernal or simply a kernel module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this programatically through any formal API. If you're willing to hack into the kernel, you probably could, but that's going to be device specific.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to create a enterprise applications that are installed by device administrators on Android Handsets to enforce enterprise mobile handset policies. Have a look at the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) for further information. There is something to disable the camera maybe there is also an option to disable USB.

This is a solution to enforce security related rules on corporate handsets. It should not be used to disable USB because it comes handy for your App.