# Exception 'open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)' on Android

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-permissions, android-storage

I am getting

> open failed: `EACCES (Permission denied)`

on the line `OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);`

I checked the root, and I tried `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

How can I fix this problem?

```
try {
    InputStream myInput;

    myInput = getAssets().open("XXX.db");

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = "/data/data/XX/databases/"
            + "XXX.db";

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // Transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
    buffer = null;
    outFileName = null;
}
catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem on an Android tablet, but my situation may be unique, so I report my solution here in a comment.  The error occurred when the app tried to access directory /data/data/myapp/foo which had over 50 xml files.  The app did not clean the folder due to a bug.  After some old files were deleted, the error disappeared. I do not know why.  It could be a problem of the generic Android device.

Comment: This solved me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission

Answer (score 253, accepted):

I had the same problem... The `<uses-permission` was in the wrong place. This is right:

```
 <manifest>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        ...
        <application>
            ...
            <activity> 
                ...
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

The `uses-permission` tag needs to be outside the `application` tag.

Comment: it is that the uses-permission needs to be outside the application

Comment: I get a warning: "`<uses-permission>` tag appears after `<application>` tag"

Comment: WARNING In android 4.4.4 do not use the parameter `android:maxSdkVersion="18"`. It was generating this exception

Comment: @guisantogui same job for me, but on Android 5.0.1. I was following the official [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) which explicitly says to include `android:maxSdkVersion="18"` for android 4.4 onwards, but obviously that isn't true

Comment: This permission is enforced starting in API level 19. Before API level 19, this permission is not enforced and all apps still have access to read from external storage.

Comment: i m using API lvl 15 , i m getting error while attempting to move file to OTG USB Stick

Comment: Very hard to find error unless you look at the log cat. It's a bit confusing if you 're using `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` as is stays silent about any errors

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem and in my code, it is already placed there still getting the same error. The problem is with Android 10 when your app targeting  API level 29.

Comment: After API 29 you will need this: https://medium.com/@sriramaripirala/android-10-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-da8b630a89df

Answer (score 419):

Google has a new feature on **Android Q**:  filtered view for external storage. A **quick fix** for that is to add this code in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest ... >
    <!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting Android Q. -->
    <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
     ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

You can read more about it  here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases

**Edit:** I am starting to get downvotes because this answer is out of date for Android 11. So whoever sees this answer please go to the link above and read the instructions.

Comment: @Billy i noticed it is only happens on devices with api 29. So i searched for changes in files provider

Comment: Finally got the cloudtestingscreenshotter_lib.aar to work with this line added to the androidTest manifest, thank you very much for this find.

Comment: I would like to read more about this nice little black magic trick, but unfortunately the link returns a 404 error ... Thanks anyway

Comment: its giving an warning `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` this wont break lower versions ryt ? @UrielFrankel

Comment: Link is still 404; is https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage the updated url?

Comment: ocramot Fixed the link

Comment: Man you saved me. I was trying everything to solve it. I was guessing the problem was Android 10 and you fixed it in just one line thank you (y)

Comment: you saved me sir this fixed the problem. But I have a question, I have two exact phones (PH-1) with exact versions (Android 10) but only one of them crache and the other doesn't crash. anyone have any idea why ?

Comment: Starting from Android 11 this is no longer valid

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala what needs to be done for android 11 any link?

Comment: @SiddarthG https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases

Comment: you sir saved my whole night...kudos, sault

Comment: ridiculous things from the authority ! extra pain for developers, why ? is this our fault that we came to android ?

Comment: I shouldn't search for this long to find this answer

Comment: thank you <3. This is working fine with my devices.

Comment: Roshana Pitigala Android 11 you need permission : "android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: @Mr. Lemon The Google Play store has a policy that limits usage of MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: No. It's not working solution.

Comment: This solution is not working for Android 13 devices.

Answer (score 370):

For API 23+ you need to request the read/write permissions even if they are already in your manifest.

```
// Storage Permissions
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};

/**
 * Checks if the app has permission to write to device storage
 *
 * If the app does not has permission then the user will be prompted to grant permissions
 *
 * @param activity
 */
public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For official documentation about requesting permissions for API 23+, check https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Just to clarify, in order for this to work, the activity must handle the activity permissions request response. See http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#handle-response for more details.

Comment: Handy link with explanation and examples here http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: isn't this a bad thing? with respect to user experience.

Comment: @usman wrt user experience, it is meant to be a good thing, since the user will be able to grant a single permission every time instead that all togheter, and the user would have a better understanding of what the application is doing on their phone. It will instead be a bad thing for user experience because the user will accept every permission request nevertheless, without even caring.

Comment: But where do I use it? for example, if I want to take a picture, do I have to run verifyStoragePermissions before startActivityForResult, or at onActivityResult? it really confuses me.

Comment: @Kiwi Lee you must use it before you decode your image. ie before using decodeFile(filepath) method

Comment: Thanks this solve my problem.
just a note:
if someone can't resolve "Manifest.permission" you just need to import "import android.Manifest".

Comment: You do not need to add READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, as WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE counts as both. Source from official documentation https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#GetWritePermission

Comment: @kldavis4 this is not required now, just request permission

Answer (score 74):

Add **android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"** to the Android Manifest
It's worked  with Android 10 (Q) at SDK 29+
or After migrating **Android X**.

```
 <application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon=""
    android:label=""
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl=""
    android:theme=""
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

Comment: not working in android 11

Comment: @famfamfam You can refer https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Answer (score 61):

I have observed this once when running the application inside the emulator. In the emulator settings, you need to specify the size of external storage ("SD Card") properly. By default, the "external storage" field is empty, and that probably means there is no such device and EACCES is thrown even if permissions are granted in the manifest.

Answer (score 53):

In addition to all the answers, make sure you're not using your phone as a USB storage.

I was having the same problem on HTC Sensation on USB storage mode enabled. I can still debug/run the app, but I can't save to external storage.

Comment: When I connect the Samsung Galaxy S6 device it first gives an option "Allow access to device data" with "DENY" or "ALLOW" and also from notification bar I am getting an option Use USB for 1. MTP 2. PTP 3. MIDI Devices 4. Charging. Which one to choose?

Answer (score 34):

My issue was with "TargetApi(23)" which is needed if your minSdkVersion is bellow 23.

So, I have request permission with the following snippet

```
protected boolean shouldAskPermissions() {
    return (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1);
}

@TargetApi(23)
protected void askPermissions() {
    String[] permissions = {
            "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
            "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    };
    int requestCode = 200;
    requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// ...
    if (shouldAskPermissions()) {
        askPermissions();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 34):

Be aware that the solution:

```
<application ...
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
```

Is temporary, sooner or later your app should be migrated to use `Scoped Storage`.

In Android 10, you can use the suggested solution to bypass the system restrictions, but in `Android 11 (R) it is mandatory to use scoped storage`, and your app might break if you kept using the old logic!

[This video](https://youtu.be/RjyYCUW-9tY) might be a good help.

Answer (score 27):

**Android 10 (API 29) introduces Scoped Storage**. Changing your manifest to request legacy storage is not a long-term solution.

I fixed the issue when I replaced my previous instances of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` (which is deprecated with API 29) with `context.getExternalFilesDir(null)`.

Note that `context.getExternalFilesDir(type)` can return null if the storage location isn't available, so be sure to check that whenever you're checking if you have external permissions.

Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped).

Comment: new error came out, ENOENT no file or dictionary

Comment: I brought its name out in logs. And now its clear `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.***)`  and `context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.***)` are different paths . Thats all. Upvoting.

Answer (score 20):

I'm experiencing the same. What I found is that if you go to **Settings -> Application Manager -> Your App -> Permissions -> Enable Storage**, it solves the issue.

Comment: I'm unable to find this section?

Answer (score 14):

It turned out, it was a stupid mistake since I had my phone still connected to the desktop PC and didn't realize this.

So I had to turn off the USB connection and everything worked fine.

Comment: I found the reason here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396757/programmatically-turn-off-usb-storage-on-android-devices also see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43863548/1729501

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem on Samsung Galaxy Note 3, running CM 12.1. The issue for me was that i had

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
```

and had to use it to take and store user photos. When I tried to load those same photos in ImageLoader i got the `(Permission denied)` error. The solution was to explicitly add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

since the above permission only limits the write permission up to API version 18, and with it the read permission.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to all answers, if the clients are using Android 6.0, Android added new [permission model](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/runtime-permissions-best-practices-and-how-to-gracefully-handle-permission-removal) for (Marshmallow).

**Trick:** If you are targeting version 22 or below, your application will request all permissions at install time just as it would on any device running an OS below Marshmallow. If  you are trying on the emulator then from android 6.0 onwards you need to explicitly go the settings->apps-> YOURAPP  -> permissions and change the permission if you have given any.

Answer (score 9):

Strangely after putting a slash **"/"** before my **newFile** my problem was solved. I changed this:

```
File myFile= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "newFile");
```

to this:

```
File myFile= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/newFile");
```

**UPDATE**:
as mentioned in the comments, the right way to do this is:

```
File myFile= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "newFile");
```

Comment: Nothing strange here. With the first line you are trying to create a file in the same directory as the one that contains your 
external storage directory. ie /storage/.../somethingnewfile instead of /storage/.../something/newfile

Comment: The correct way to do this is to use the File(dir, file) cosntructor

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and none of suggestions helped. But I found an interesting reason for that, on a physical device, [Galaxy Tab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Tab_series).

When USB storage is on, external storage read and write permissions don't have any effect.
Just turn off USB storage, and with the correct permissions, you'll have the problem solved.

Answer (score 6):

To store a file in a `directory` which is foreign to the app's directory is *restricted* above `API 29+`. So to generate a new file or to create a new file use your application directory like this :-

So the correct approach is :-

```
val file = File(appContext.applicationInfo.dataDir + File.separator + "anyRandomFileName/")
```

You can write any data into this generated file !

The above `file` is accessible and would not `throw any exception` because it resides in your own **developed app's** directory.

The other option is  `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in `manifest application tag` as suggested by `Uriel` but its not a permanent solution !

Comment: Thanks, however, this answer might not apply in the case where the said exception occurs as a result of trying to READ a file the user selected from file system - that is, the file already exists. And moreover, I already added the suggested parameters to the application's manifest.

Answer (score 5):

I would expect everything below `/data` to belong to "internal storage". You should, however, be able to write to `/sdcard`.

Comment: I tried <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" /> too. still same.

Comment: The /data-partition is generally write-protected to ordinary (non-root) users trying to to ordinary file access. For internal storage, there are specialized methods to do so, especially if you want to access databases. The [Android developer pages](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) should help you on this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Change a permission property in your `/system/etc/permission/platform.xml`
and group need to mentioned as like below.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
    <group android:gid="sdcard_rw" />
    <group android:gid="media_rw" />    
</uses-permission>
```

Comment: Fail. Put my device into a boot loop.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error when was trying to write an image in DCIM/camera folder on Galaxy S5 (android 6.0.1) and I figured out that only this folder is restricted. I simply could write into DCIM/any folder but not in camera.
This should be brand based restriction/customization.

Answer (score 4):

When your application belongs to the system application, it can't access the SD card.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the answer is this:

on the API >= 23 devices, if you install app (the app is not system app), you should check the storage permission in "Setting - applications", there is permission list for every app, you should check it on! try

Answer (score 4):

keep in mind that even if you set all the correct permissions in the manifest:
 The only place 3rd party apps are allowed to write on your external card are "their own directories" 
(i.e. /sdcard/Android/data/)
trying to write to anywhere else: you will get exception:
    EACCES (Permission denied)

Answer (score 4):

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory();
```

When using this deprecated method from Android 29 onwards you will receive the same error:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

Resolution here:

[getExternalStoragePublicDirectory deprecated in Android Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468539/getexternalstoragepublicdirectory-deprecated-in-android-q)

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was using a [file picker library](https://github.com/spacecowboy/NoNonsense-FilePicker) which returned the path to external storage but it started from `/root/`. And even with the *WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE* permission granted at runtime I still got error **EACCES (Permission denied)**. 
So use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the correct path to external storage.

Example: 
*Cannot write:* `/root/storage/emulated/0/newfile.txt`
*Can write:* `/storage/emulated/0/newfile.txt`

```
boolean externalStorageWritable = isExternalStorageWritable();
File file = new File(filePath);
boolean canWrite = file.canWrite();
boolean isFile = file.isFile();
long usableSpace = file.getUsableSpace();

Log.d(TAG, "externalStorageWritable: " + externalStorageWritable);
Log.d(TAG, "filePath: " + filePath);
Log.d(TAG, "canWrite: " + canWrite);
Log.d(TAG, "isFile: " + isFile);
Log.d(TAG, "usableSpace: " + usableSpace);

/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Output 1:

```
externalStorageWritable: true
filePath: /root/storage/emulated/0/newfile.txt
isFile: false
usableSpace: 0
```

Output 2:

```
externalStorageWritable: true
filePath: /storage/emulated/0/newfile.txt
isFile: true
usableSpace: 1331007488
```

Answer (score 2):

I am creating a folder under /data/ in my init.rc (mucking around with the aosp on Nexus 7) and had exactly this problem.

It turned out that giving the folder rw (666) permission was not sufficient and it had to be rwx (777) then it all worked!

Answer (score 2):

The post 6.0 enforcement of storage permissions can be bypassed if you have a rooted device via these adb commands:

```
root@msm8996:/ # getenforce
getenforce
Enforcing
root@msm8996:/ # setenforce 0
setenforce 0
root@msm8996:/ # getenforce
getenforce
Permissive
```

Answer (score 2):

i faced the same error on xiaomi devices (android 10 ). The following code fixed my problem.
Libraries: Dexter(https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) and Image picker(https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker)

Add manifest ( android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true")

```
    public void showPickImageSheet(AddImageModel model) {
    BottomSheetHelper.showPickImageSheet(this, new BottomSheetHelper.PickImageDialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChooseFromGalleryClicked(Dialog dialog) {
            selectedImagePickerPosition = model.getPosition();
            Dexter.withContext(OrderReviewActivity.this)                   .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                            if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                                ImagePicker.with(OrderReviewActivity.this)
                                        .galleryOnly()
                                        .compress(512)
                                        .maxResultSize(852,480)
                               .start();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> list, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                            permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                        }

                    }).check();

            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTakePhotoClicked(Dialog dialog) {
            selectedImagePickerPosition = model.getPosition();
            ImagePicker.with(OrderReviewActivity.this)
                    .cameraOnly()
                    .compress(512)
                    .maxResultSize(852,480)
                    .start();

            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelButtonClicked(Dialog dialog) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was appearing on the line

```
      target.createNewFile();
```

since I could not create a new file on the sd card,so I had to use the DocumentFile approach.

```
      documentFile.createFile(mime, target.getName());
```

For the above question the problem may be solved with this approach,

```
    fos=context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(documentFile.getUri());
```

See this thread too,
         [How to use the new SD card access API presented for Android 5.0 (Lollipop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744842/how-to-use-the-new-sd-card-access-api-presented-for-android-5-0-lollipop)

Answer (score 1):

I Use the below process to handle the case with android 11 and targetapi30

1. As pre-created file dir as per scoped storage in my case in root dir files//<Image/Video... as per requirement>
2. Copy picked file and copy the file in cache directory at the time of picking from my external storage
3. Then at a time to upload ( on my send/upload button click) copy the file from cache dir to my scoped storage dir and then do my upload process

use this solution due to at time upload app in play store it generates warning for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and sometimes rejected from play store in my case.

Also as we used target API 30 so we can't share or forward file from our internal storage to app

Answer (score 1):

2022 Kotlin way to ask permission:

```
private val writeStoragePermissionResult =
   registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->}

private fun askForStoragePermission(): Boolean =
   if (hasPermissions(
           requireContext(),
           Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
           Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
       )
   ) {
       true
   } else {
       writeStoragePermissionResult.launch(
           arrayOf(
               Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
               Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
           )
       )
       false
   }

fun hasPermissions(context: Context, vararg permissions: String): Boolean = permissions.all {
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (API >= 23).

The solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/13569364/1729501 worked for me, but it was not practical to disconnect app for debugging.

my solution was to install proper adb device driver on Windows. The google USB driver did not work for my device.

STEP 1: Download adb drivers for your device brand.

STEP 2: Go to device manager -> other devices -> look for entries with word "adb" -> select Update driver -> give location in step 1

Answer (score 0):

Add gradle dependencies

```
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
```

Add below code in your main activity.

```
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.MultiplePermissionsReport;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.multi.MultiplePermissionsListener;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                checkMermission();
            }
        }, 4000);
    }

    private void checkMermission(){
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermissions(
                        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                        Manifest.permission.INTERNET
                ).withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()){
                    checkMermission();
                } else if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()){
                    // copy some things
                } else {
                    checkMermission();
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                token.continuePermissionRequest();
            }
        }).check();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this crash while running the junit4 test of Jetpack Macrobenchmark in a real device?

If yes then increase the version of `androidx.profileinstaller:profileinstaller`.

Just click this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/profileinstaller), find stable version and add to build.gradle(app).

For example `implement(androidx.profileinstaller:profileinstaller:1.3.0)`.

I found it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203598149

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem and solved the problem with this method

```
   suspend fun copyFileToInternalStorage(context: Context,uri: Uri, newDirName: String): String? {
    val returnCursor = context.contentResolver.query(
        uri, arrayOf(
            OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, OpenableColumns.SIZE
        ), null, null, null
    )


    /*
     * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
     *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
     *     * and display it.
     * */
    val nameIndex = returnCursor!!.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
    val sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
    returnCursor.moveToFirst()
    val name = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex)
    val output: File = if (newDirName != "") {
        val dir =
            File(context.filesDir.toString() + "/" + newDirName)
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir()
        }
        File(context.filesDir.toString() + "/" + newDirName + "/" + name)
    } else {
        File(context.filesDir.toString() + "/" + name)
    }
    try {
        val inputStream =
            context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(output)
        var read = 0
        val bufferSize = 1024
        val buffers = ByteArray(bufferSize)
        while (inputStream!!.read(buffers).also { read = it } != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read)
        }
        inputStream.close()
        outputStream.close()
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        Log.e("Exception", e.message!!)
    }
    return output.path
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is receiving this error using a hybrid app, using for example **ionic**, and the previous solutions did not work, first confirm that the path is valid.

If the error is coming from **downloadFile** or **writeFile**, confirm that there is not already a file in the location, it was my error.

The ionic standard library does not 'overwrite' and will throw an exception if the target file already exists, when trying to download or write. in this case the downloadFile itself tries to open and will throw **EACCES exception**

Solution:

If this is your problem you can save the file name with `_${Date.now()} at the end of the name or verify if the file exists and delete it before creating a new one.

[issue](https://github.com/capacitor-community/http/issues/52)

Answer (score 0):

For API 33+ you need to request this permission to read Images

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />

    String[] permissionNew = new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES};
    String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};



private boolean checkPermissions() {
    int result;
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        for (String p : permissionsNew) {
            result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(), p);
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (String p : permissions) {
            result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(), p);
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
            }
        }
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        requestPermissions(listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), 200);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add Permission in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: There is no permission `android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE`

Answer (score -2):

add this to manifest but this permission has a google play policy.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```