# Is it possible to scan the pixels of a huge image on Android without OutOfMemory errors?

Tags: android, image-processing

When I take a picture using my Android phone, the photo is too large to be loaded directly into my app, so I have to scale the Bitmap down.

I would like to do some image analysis (thresholding) on Android, so I don't want to scale the image down too much. Is it even possible to view all pixel data from a huge image file?

Comment: Load and process chunks at a time.

Comment: Whay do you mean by to big? 100 MB or 1GB ?

Comment: If you are targetting API Level 11+, you can set android:largeHeap="true" on the <application> element in the manifest to request a larger-than-normal heap size

Comment: @Vash-DamianLeszczyński around 10MB.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039672/android-how-to-read-file-in-bytes