# Error while converting file to bytes

Tags: android, parse-platform

i'm getting the the following error  bad json response: org.json.JSONException: Value Invalid of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject. can any one tell me how to convert a file to bytes in android and store it in parse cloud...

```
            InputStream inputstream=assetmanager.open("lmh.jpg");
            byte[] data=new byte[inputstream.available()];                  
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile("lmh.jpg", data);
            file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(e!=null)
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR: "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sucess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                ParseObject fileu = new ParseObject("FileU");
                fileu.put("image", file);
                fileu.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are just passing empty byte array. You should first try to convert your image into byte array appropriately:

```
// make sure image path is correct

InputStream inputStream=assetmanager.open("lmh.jpg");
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS= new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOS);
byte[] data= baos.toByteArray();

ParseFile file = new ParseFile("lmh.jpg", data);
```

Also, make sure your client key is copied correctly: [similar error](https://www.parse.com/questions/android-parse-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject)

Comment: i'm sure my client key is copied correctly.. how to convert file to byte array

Comment: @twinkie Is above code not working? I already put code which converts image file into byte array.

Comment: @twinkie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039672/android-how-to-read-file-in-bytes

Comment: for text and word files?