# Converting cURL command to retrofit call

Tags: android, curl, retrofit2

I'm trying to convert a cURL command to a retrofit call. 
The cURL command is:

```
curl -u {username}:{password} -X POST
--header "Content-Type: audio/wav" 
--header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" 
--data-binary @{audiofile}.wav 
"{url}" -i -v
```

I already converted the -u command by adding a Base64 of the username and password as the Authorization header. I've also added the other header. However the problem is with the retrofit call. 
The Retrofit call is currently:

```
@POST
@Headers({"Transfer-Encoding: chunked", "Content-Type: audio/wav"})
Call<Station> translateAudio(@Url String url, @Header("Authorization") String auth,
        @Body RequestBody file);
```

When using the cURL command the audio file gets processed correctly on the server. However when I try the retrofit call I'm getting an error from the service I'm using. It seems there is a difference between the retrofit call and the cURL one. Does anyone know what the difference is? The credentials do get accepted, so that's not the problem.

Comment: What kind of error do you receive?

Comment: @jonas.koeritz: 
The error is: 
{
 "code_description": "Bad Request",
 "code": 400,
 "error": "unable to transcode data stream audio/wav -> audio/x-float-array "
}

However that's specific to that service. Maybe it could help with searching for the difference of sending the file.

Comment: How do you create your `file` object?

Comment: @jonas.koeritz: I created my file object by using new File(Environment.getExternalStorage()+"/file.wav"). The file is valid and the app has permission to read the file.

Comment: The cause of the problem might be that retrofit sends the binary representation of the File Object itself, not the Files contents to the server.

Comment: @jonas.koeritz that's a possibility. Do you know perhaps how to send the contents of the file instead of the representation of the File object?

Answer (score 0):

Your code tries to send an Android `File` Object to the server. You have to read the file into a byte array or other suitable structure first to send the real contents to the server.

[See this question for a quick solution how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039672/android-how-to-read-file-in-bytes)

Comment: I tried sending the data by byte array however this did not solve the problem. I still get the same response. The method I used to create the RequestBody is RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/wav"), bytes);