# Android canRead() returns false

Tags: java, android

I received a file from an intent like so:

```
Uri incoming = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
File toStream = new File(incoming.getPath());
```

I cannot read from it, and toStream.canRead() returns false.

I received this from the share button in the Gallery app, and other apps seem to be receiving this file just fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

Comment: Where do you have the code - toStream.canRead(), because in the doc here "http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#canRead()" it's said - "Indicates whether the current context is allowed to read from this file." so the context could be the problem.

Comment: Stacks28's code does the same thing as mine as far as I can tell.  Same results.

Comment: I read about that too, but what could the context change?  I have the read external storage permission set in the manifest.

Comment: goody:  I have the .canRead() code running inside the onCreate() of a FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new issue in SDK 23+ with permissions, which can cause your read/write to fail even though you fixed it in the manifest. It is discussed under permissions even though you first encounter it when you try read/write.
[Link to thread where it is discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);`. The path which was returned, was something like "**/document/primary:Download/a.c**" . When I create File object with that path, it was showing `exists()` and `canRead()` as `false`. What I did was, took the path after "**:**",  that is "**Download/a.c**" and merged that with "**/storage/emulated/0/**". So final path is "**/storage/emulated/0/Download/a.c**" . Worked fine with internal storage.

In case of only permission problem make use of this.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},THIS_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and override this

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding permission to your app [READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Comment: I have that permission set.  That's what I suspected at first too.