# Open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) in Android

Tags: android, permission-denied, read-write

I found a code and edited a bit according to my application. It is about writing a text to txt on Android in bytes. I'm getting this error, [Exception 'open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)' on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/android-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied)

As stated in the link above, I changed its place where user-permission related to write_external_storage is located in my Android Manifest file. However, in that file, I received " tag appears after  tag" Warning leading me to get the same error again.

Thank you in advance

```
 if (response.equals("tag OK " + param[2]
                + " authenticated (Success)")) {

             mySuccessfulLogin = param[0] + "\n"
                    + param[1] + "\n" + param[2]
                    + "\n" + newpassword;

            myDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"Users/macbookpro/Documents/CS328/Android_IMAP";

            File custdir = new File(myDirectory);
            if(!custdir.exists())
                {
                    custdir.mkdirs();

                }

            File savedir=new File(custdir.getAbsolutePath());
            File file = new File(savedir, "LastLogin");

            if(file.exists())
                 {
               file.delete();
                 }

            FileOutputStream fos;

            byte[] data = mySuccessfulLogin.getBytes();

            try {

                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                               // Toast.makeText(, "File Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error File Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               Log.e("fnf", ""+e.getMessage());
                                // handle exception
              } catch (IOException e) {
                                // handle exception
                               // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error IO Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }

        }
```

Comment: Post your logs please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

before the application tag.

Comment: If you have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission you don't need READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but yes, he does need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: I had done whatever you told me before. At that time, It didn't work. But this time it works, but I cannot find it in my directory. Do you guys have any idea about it? @Guardanis

Comment: @Lukos, my txt file named LastLogin.txt ( it doesn't appear in the code that way but I changed it later on) if it is the way it is stored in the directory.

Comment: It looks like you delete it right after you create it.

Comment: @Lukos, I removed that part, and it didn't work. I cannot see that. I mean there is nothing like there because of a reason I don't know