# Android save text file

Tags: android

The question is pretty common and I have googled it a few but I still have problems. I have to save in a text file some data for a game that I am trying to develop. This is the code:

```
if (!isSecond(game[k])) {

            //Where I'd like to save the file
            File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/flagQuiz/record.txt");

             //Try to save my file
             try {

                myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                        new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

                //correctGuess and TimeElapsed are two integers
                myOutWriter.append(String.valueOf(correctGuess) + "-" + String.valueOf(TimeElapsed));
                myOutWriter.close();
                fOut.close();

             } catch (IOException e) {

                 e.printStackTrace();

             }

}
```

The log cat shows me this kind of error:

[image]

I have declared the possibility to save stuff in the SD Card in this way I guess:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Where is the mistake? flagQuiz folder is already created at runtime.

Comment: You should create the folder `flagQuiz` first

Comment: I have just edited the main question, flagQuiz already exists!

Comment: manifest file?  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />? all set?

Comment: Can you print the result of myFile.getAbsolutePath() before createNewFile()

Comment: Testing in android device or emulator?

Comment: I am testing in an emulator

Comment: Yup there is the issue :) ... Test in android device.. I think for testing in emulator we have to do setting(I donot Know just making assumption)

Comment: If just for saving two integer values, why don't you use `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android .. Check this. Hope this answer help you testing in emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to check if `file.exists()` if `true` then delete it and create new one 
else `false` then just carry on with your `try` block