# Error reading the file from /data directory on rooted android phone. java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, android-sdcard

This is my code where i'm trying to access a file from /data directory on my rooted device. My app is successfully getting root privileges and also, it can access data from other folders like / or /sdcard or /system etc. The problem arises only in the case of /data directory. And, i'm sure such file exists on the file system and getting the correct path. If the file doesn't exist, then it shows a different error. Now, how can i read the file inside /data directory?

```
try {

            File wifiConfFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()+ File.separator + "system" + File.separator + "appops.xml");

            if(!wifiConfFile.exists()){
                Log.d("FILE", Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/system/appops.xml couldn't be loaded!");
            }
            fis = new FileInputStream(wifiConfFile);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            wifiDesc.append(sb.toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is the permission block in my android-menifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And, this is from android monitor...

```
12-08 19:47:28.326 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/appops.xml: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
12-08 19:47:28.326 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
12-08 19:47:28.326 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
12-08 19:47:28.326 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at rizanamic.wifipass.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71)
12-08 19:47:28.326 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
12-08 19:47:28.326 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
12-08 19:47:28.326 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
12-08 19:47:28.326 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
12-08 19:47:28.326 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
12-08 19:47:28.326 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
12-08 19:47:28.326 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-08 19:47:28.326 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-08 19:47:28.326 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5229)
12-08 19:47:28.327 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-08 19:47:28.327 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-08 19:47:28.327 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
12-08 19:47:28.327 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
12-08 19:47:28.327 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
12-08 19:47:28.327 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
12-08 19:47:28.327 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
12-08 19:47:28.327 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
12-08 19:47:28.327 26634-26634/rizanamic.wifipass W/System.err:     ... 15 more
```

Comment: I think you can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android

Comment: 'Now, how can i read the file inside /data directory? '. Wrong question. You should have asked 'why cannot i read the file /data/system/appops.xml?'. Why do you think such a file would exist?

Comment: @greenapps I'm talking about any file inside /data.

Comment: @D-Han I've even checked permissions at run time (feature offered in marshmallow). They are all granted! There doesn't be any problem with permission of reading and writing to external storage as per my permission check method.

Comment: You don't know where you are talking about. You don't need EXTERNAL permissions while trying to read from INTERNAL memory.