# android permissions to write on external storage fail

Tags: codenameone

Am unable to write to external storage in android. I do get the following stacktrace:
01-14 10:57:07.108: W/System.err(17380): java.io.FileNotFoundException:

```
/mnt/media_rw/extSdCard/SterlingPixels.apk: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
01-14 10:57:07.108: W/System.err(17380):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
01-14 10:57:07.108: W/System.err(17380):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
01-14 10:57:07.108: W/System.err(17380):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:127)
01-14 10:57:07.108: W/System.err(17380):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116)
01-14 10:57:07.108: W/System.err(17380):    at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation.createFileOuputStream(AndroidImplementation.java:4258)
01-14 10:57:07.108: W/System.err(17380):    at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation.openFileOutputStream(AndroidImplementation.java:4210)
01-14 10:57:07.108: W/System.err(17380):    at com.codename1.io.FileSystemStorage.openOutputStream(FileSystemStorage.java:263)
01-14 10:57:07.108: W/System.err(17380):    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.readResponse(ConnectionRequest.java:783)
01-14 10:57:07.108: W/System.err(17380):    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:440)
01-14 10:57:07.108: W/System.err(17380):    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:263)
01-14 10:57:07.108: W/System.err(17380):    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
01-14 10:57:07.108: W/System.err(17380):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
01-14 10:57:07.108: W/System.err(17380): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
01-14 10:57:07.108: W/System.err(17380):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
01-14 10:57:07.108: W/System.err(17380):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
01-14 10:57:07.108: W/System.err(17380):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
01-14 10:57:07.108: W/System.err(17380):    ... 11 more
```

I cant include `"<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>"` in build hints, as this causes the build to fail on merging the manifests..so i assume the build system creates this permission correctly. Except it does not work. Or am i mistaken?

Comment: Is it possible your device is connected as a USB - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android

Answer (score 1):

I had usb connected indeed, but that did  not resolve my problems right away after disconnecting it. So,at first i was getting the path to write the file as follows:

```
 String root = roots[0];
        for (String root1 : roots) {
            if (FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getRootType(root1) == FileSystemStorage.ROOT_TYPE_MAINSTORAGE) {
                root = root1;
                break;
            }
        }
        root= root + FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getFileSystemSeparator();
```

For some strange reason, the above code was always returning external storage; i imagine it is supposed to return internal phone storage. So this always gave me the permissions headache. This is on Android 5.1.1.

I did change this to

```
String root = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath();
```

which of course worked, but this certainly does not address the permission  problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in Codename One as it is requested by default. Newer builds migrated to [gradle](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/material-icons-background-music-geofencing-gradle.html) which is more strict than Ant on manifest usage so you are getting the error.

Make sure your device isn't connected as a mass storage device which sometimes causes a conflict in file access on sd card.