# Android: FTPClient java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, ftp

Im using this library for the ftp upload:

http://androidexample.com/FTP_File_Upload_From_Sdcard_to_server/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=98

This my code but it isnt working:

```
 FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

                        try {

                            client.connect("xx.xx.xx.xx", 21);
                            client.login("xxx", "xx");
                            client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
                            client.changeDirectory("/picts_products/");

                            File f = new File("/logo.png");

                            client.upload(f);
```

I alway get this error: java.io.FileNotFoundException. Do you know why?

**UPDATE!**

Since API 23 the permissions must be checked by the activity! This solved my problem:

[Exception 'open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)' on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android)

Comment: Yes, I know why! The file wasn't found at that path, just like the error says. Perhaps try "./logo.png", if the file is in your project base directory?

Comment: This doesnt work too. Actually I create a file and put that in the upload. In the example from http://androidexample.com/FTP_File_Upload_From_Sdcard_to_server/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=98 they do the same. Do you know any other way?

Comment: I also tryed with Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES