# Video Selection from gallery code not working for Marshmallow, but working for Lollipop - Android

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have implemented a code to select a video from gallery and play it in videoview. It works very well in lollipop version. But today when I checked it on Marshmallow, It is not working. There is no exception in logcat too.

Is it due to some security that is added in Marshmallow that is not allowing me to select the video or are any runtime permission needed?
I have this permissions in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Following is my code:

```
      Intent pickVideoImage= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
      pickVideoImage.setType("*/*");
      String[] mimetypes = {"image/*", "video/*"};
      pickVideoImage.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
      startActivityForResult(pickVideoImage,SELECT_PICTURE_VIDEO);
```

And this is the code inside onActivityResult :

```
      path = data.getData().toString();
      vid.setVideoPath(path);
      vid.start();
```

Comment: I hope this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android/40277322#40277322) will help you

Answer (score 0):

you should allow permissions on Runtime for Android Marshmallow Version 6.0

Comment: Can you please update your answer showing how to add the permission? It will make your answer much more accessible.