# JOGL Android App can't write to external storage

Tags: java, android, jogl

I have an Android app that uses JOGL for OpenGL graphics.  The app is the GearsTestDemo that is used in other places for testing.  The app runs and displays on two different tablet devices, one running 4.4.2 an the other running 4.1.2.  I am trying to add file access.  I have write and read permissions specified in the manifest file.  I can write to local app storage (after battling with getting the correct Context).  When I try to write to external storage I get  open failed: EACCES (Permission denied).  A snippet of logcat output is given below showing the error.  Since the permissions appear to be set correctly in the manifest it seems that JOGL is somehow interfering with the app's ability to write.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gdeb.tango.JOGL_GearsTest"
    android:versionCode="19"
    android:versionName="1.9" > 


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="20"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:description="@string/app_descr"
                 android:persistent="false"
                 >

        <activity android:name="com.gdeb.tango.JOGL_GearsTest.JOGL_GearsTestActivityLauncher"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
                  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the Activity code

```
/**
 * Copyright 2011 JogAmp Community. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are
 * permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *
 *    1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of
 *       conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *    2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list
 *       of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials
 *       provided with the distribution.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY JogAmp Community ``AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED
 * WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL JogAmp Community OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
 * CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
 * SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON
 * ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF
 * ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 * The views and conclusions contained in the software and documentation are those of the
 * authors and should not be interpreted as representing official policies, either expressed
 * or implied, of JogAmp Community.
 */
package com.gdeb.tango.JOGL_GearsTest;

import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile;

import jogamp.newt.driver.android.NewtBaseActivity;

import com.jogamp.common.util.InterruptSource;
import com.jogamp.newt.event.MonitorEvent;
import com.jogamp.newt.event.MouseAdapter;
import com.jogamp.newt.event.MouseEvent;
import com.jogamp.newt.event.MonitorModeListener;
import com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow;

import com.jogamp.opengl.util.Animator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

// KRF
// test of android log4j
//import de.mindpipe.android.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator;
import android.os.Environment;
import java.io.File;
//import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import android.content.Context;

//public class NEWTGearsES2Activity extends NewtBaseActivity {
public class JOGL_GearsTestActivity extends NewtBaseActivity {
   //static String TAG = "NEWTGearsES2Activity";
   static String TAG = "JOGLGearsTestActivity";

   static final String forceRGBA5650 = "demo.force.rgba5650";
   static final String forceECT = "demo.force.ect";
   static final String forceKillProcessTest = "demo.force.killProcessTest";

   //   KRF
//   private LogConfigurator logConfigurator;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       Log.d(TAG, "onCreate - 0");
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


       // KRF
//       logConfigurator = new LogConfigurator();
//// dump
//Log.d(TAG, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "gears_test.txt");
//       logConfigurator.setFileName(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "gears_test.txt");
//       // Set the root log level
//       logConfigurator.setRootLevel(Level.DEBUG);
//       // Set log level of a specific logger
//       logConfigurator.setLevel("org.apache", Level.ERROR);
//       logConfigurator.setLevel("com.gdeb", Level.INFO);
//       logConfigurator.configure();

       // create GLWindow (-> incl. underlying NEWT Display, Screen & Window)
       final GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2ES2));
       if( null != System.getProperty(forceRGBA5650) ) {
           Log.d(TAG, "forceRGBA5650");
           caps.setRedBits(5); caps.setGreenBits(6); caps.setBlueBits(5);
       }

       Log.d(TAG, "req caps: "+caps);
       final GLWindow glWindow = GLWindow.create(caps);
       glWindow.setFullscreen(true);
       setContentView(getWindow(), glWindow);

       //final GearsES2 demo = new GearsES2(-1);
       final GearsES2 demo = new GearsES2();

       // demo.enableAndroidTrace(true);
       glWindow.addGLEventListener(demo);
       glWindow.getScreen().addMonitorModeListener(new MonitorModeListener() {
           @Override
           public void monitorModeChangeNotify(final MonitorEvent me) { }
           @Override
           public void monitorModeChanged(final MonitorEvent me, final boolean success) {
               System.err.println("MonitorMode Changed (success "+success+"): "+me);
           }
       });

       if( null != System.getProperty(forceKillProcessTest) ) {
           Log.d(TAG, "not forceKillProcessTest");
       }
       else {
           Log.d(TAG, "forceKillProcessTest");
       }
           Log.d(TAG, "force forceKillProcessTest");
           glWindow.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
                if( e.getPointerCount() == 3 ) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "MemoryHog");
                    new InterruptSource.Thread(null, new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            final ArrayList<Buffer> buffers = new ArrayList<Buffer>();
                            while(true) {
                                //final int halfMB = 512 * 1024;
                                final int tenMB = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
                                final float osizeMB = buffers.size() * 10.0f;
                                final float nsizeMB = osizeMB + 10.0f;
                                System.err.println("MemoryHog: ****** +4k: "+osizeMB+" MB +"+nsizeMB+" MB - Try");
                                //buffers.add(ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(halfMB)); // 0.5 MB each
                                buffers.add(ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tenMB)); // 10.0 MB each
                                System.err.println("MemoryHog: ****** +4k: "+osizeMB+" MB +"+nsizeMB+" MB - Done");
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(200);
                                } catch (final Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); };
                            }
                        } }, "MemoryHog").start();
                } else if( e.getPointerCount() == 4 ) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ForceKill");
                    android.os.Process.killProcess( android.os.Process.myPid() );
                }
            }
           });
       //}

       final Animator animator = new Animator(glWindow);
       // animator.setRunAsFastAsPossible(true);
       // glWindow.setSkipContextReleaseThread(animator.getThread());

       if( null != System.getProperty(forceECT) ) {
           Log.d(TAG, "forceECT");
           animator.setExclusiveContext(true);
       }

       glWindow.setVisible(true);

       animator.setUpdateFPSFrames(60, System.err);
       animator.resetFPSCounter();
       glWindow.resetFPSCounter();

//================================
       // KRF
       // ??? filenotfound error, permissions?
       Log.d(TAG, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "markar" + File.separator + "test1.txt");
       File tFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "markar" + File.separator + "test1.txt");
       //File tFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "test.txt");
       try {
         OutputStream outS = new FileOutputStream(tFile);
         outS.write((int) 5); 
         outS.close();
         Log.d(TAG, "writing to external test.txt");
       } catch (final Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); };


       // Try internal storage
       try {
         //File tLFile =  this.getFileStreamPath("test.txt");
         //Log.d(TAG, tLFile.getAbsolutePath());
         //OutputStream outLS = new FileOutputStream(tLFile);

         //Context ctx = createPackageContext("com.gdeb.tango.JOGL_GearsTest", CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
         Context ctx = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
         OutputStream outLS = ctx.openFileOutput("test.txt",MODE_PRIVATE);
         outLS.write((int) 5); 
         outLS.close();
         Log.d(TAG, "writing to internal test.txt");
       } catch (final Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); };


//     Checks if external storage is available for read and write
       String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
       if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
         Log.d(TAG, "External storage available");
       }
       else {
         Log.d(TAG, "External storage NOT available");
       }

//     Checks if external storage is available to at least read
       String st = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
       if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(st) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(st)) {
         Log.d(TAG, "External storage readable");
       }
       else {
         Log.d(TAG, "External storage NOT readable");
       }

//================================

       Log.d(TAG, "onCreate - X");
   }
}
```

And here is the snippet of logcat output showing the error.  Notice that this points to onCreate(JOGL_GearsTestActivity.java:176) as the source of the error.

```
...
...
04-15 14:26:36.023: W/System.err(7281): GLWindow.setVisibleActionPost(true, false) main-Display-.android_nil-1-EDT-5, start
04-15 14:26:36.023: W/System.err(7281): GLWindow.setVisibleActionPost(true, false) main-Display-.android_nil-1-EDT-5, fin: dt 0.144334ms
04-15 14:26:36.023: W/System.err(7281): Window setVisible: END (main-Display-.android_nil-1-EDT-5) state [visible, autopos, fullscreen, ], nativeWindowCreated: false, madeVisible: -1, geom 0/0 0x0, windowHandle 0x0
04-15 14:26:36.023: W/System.err(7281): GLWindow.resetCounter() main-Display-.android_nil-1-EDT-5
04-15 14:26:36.024: D/JOGLGearsTestActivity(7281): /storage/emulated/0/markar/test1.txt
04-15 14:26:36.024: W/System.err(7281): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/markar/test1.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
04-15 14:26:36.024: W/System.err(7281):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
04-15 14:26:36.024: W/System.err(7281):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
04-15 14:26:36.025: W/System.err(7281):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
04-15 14:26:36.025: W/System.err(7281):     at com.gdeb.tango.JOGL_GearsTest.JOGL_GearsTestActivity.onCreate(JOGL_GearsTestActivity.java:176)
04-15 14:26:36.025: W/System.err(7281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-15 14:26:36.025: W/System.err(7281):     at jogamp.android.launcher.ActivityLauncher.callMethod(ActivityLauncher.java:237)
04-15 14:26:36.025: W/System.err(7281):     at jogamp.android.launcher.ActivityLauncher.onCreate(ActivityLauncher.java:91)
04-15 14:26:36.025: W/System.err(7281):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-15 14:26:36.025: W/System.err(7281):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-15 14:26:36.025: W/System.err(7281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2160)
04-15 14:26:36.025: W/System.err(7281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
04-15 14:26:36.025: W/System.err(7281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:136)
04-15 14:26:36.026: W/System.err(7281):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
04-15 14:26:36.026: W/System.err(7281):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-15 14:26:36.026: W/System.err(7281):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-15 14:26:36.026: W/System.err(7281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5030)
04-15 14:26:36.026: W/System.err(7281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-15 14:26:36.026: W/System.err(7281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-15 14:26:36.026: W/System.err(7281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
04-15 14:26:36.026: W/System.err(7281): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
04-15 14:26:36.026: W/System.err(7281):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
04-15 14:26:36.026: W/System.err(7281):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
04-15 14:26:36.027: W/System.err(7281):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
04-15 14:26:36.027: W/System.err(7281):     ... 18 more
04-15 14:26:36.027: D/JOGLGearsTestActivity(7281): writing to internal test.txt
04-15 14:26:36.028: D/JOGLGearsTestActivity(7281): External storage available
04-15 14:26:36.028: D/JOGLGearsTestActivity(7281): External storage readable
04-15 14:26:36.028: D/JOGLGearsTestActivity(7281): onCreate - X
04-15 14:26:36.029: D/JogAmp-ActivityLauncher(7281): onCreate - X
04-15 14:26:36.029: D/JogAmp-ActivityLauncher(7281): onStart - S
...
...
```

Yes, the external storage shows up as readable from getExternalStorageState().
Yes, the intermediate directory specified in the external file, "markar", exists.
I cut/pasted this code in another project in onCreate() and it worked fine.
Using Eclipse.  Connected to device by USB for ADB, connected as Media Device.
JOGL issue?

Comment: You should look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android JOGL is probably not to blame, there are numerous other possible culprits. If this is really JOGL specific, please rather post in our official JogAmp forum.

Comment: I looked through that post and did not find anything that helped.  I posted to the jogamp forum [link](http://forum.jogamp.org/Write-to-SD-card-on-Android-td4036661.html).  Mentioned there, I did find a curious line in some release notes that hint at write-sd being disabled.