# Permission denied when writing a RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, android

Edit: My question isn't duplicate of [Android permission doesn't work even if I have declared it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it) because i have asked for permission at runtime

Edit2: Writing file into `Environment.getexternalstoragedirectory` is ok but to sdcard gives that error

Hey I'm trying to write a mp3 file with `RandomAccessFile` to sdcard and this is my code:

```
public void save(String newFilename) throws IOException, NotSupportedException {
    if (file.compareTo(new File(newFilename)) == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Save filename same as source filename");
    }
    RandomAccessFile saveFile = new RandomAccessFile(newFilename, "rw");
    try {
        if (hasId3v2Tag()) {
            saveFile.write(id3v2Tag.toBytes());
        }
        saveMpegFrames(saveFile);
        if (hasCustomTag()) {
            saveFile.write(customTag);
        }
        if (hasId3v1Tag()) {
            saveFile.write(id3v1Tag.toBytes());
        }
    } finally {
        saveFile.close();
    }
}

private void saveMpegFrames(RandomAccessFile saveFile) throws IOException {
    int filePos = xingOffset;
    if (filePos < 0) filePos = startOffset;
    if (filePos < 0) return;
    if (endOffset < filePos) return;
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(this.file.getPath(), "r");
    byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferLength];
    try {
        randomAccessFile.seek(filePos);
        while (true) {
            int bytesRead = randomAccessFile.read(bytes, 0, bufferLength);
            if (filePos + bytesRead <= endOffset) {
                saveFile.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
                filePos += bytesRead;
            } else {
                saveFile.write(bytes, 0, endOffset - filePos + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    } finally {
        randomAccessFile.close();
    }
}
```

and I'm getting this error in `logcat`:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/15D5-14F7/Musics/Music/Dream On.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

but i have Write and Read permission why is this happening?

Comment: thanks i will do that and excuse me for my bad english @MikeM.

Comment: refer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android

Comment: thanks but i've did all of them @sasikumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/15D5-14F7/Musics/Music/Dream On.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

That appears to be a location on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). You do not have read or write access to arbitrary locations on removable storage on Android 4.4+ devices.

> but i have Write and Read permission

You might have read and/or write permission to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). External storage is not removable storage.

Comment: so how can i get access to removable storage? some application do that like RAR

Comment: Use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`) to allow users to pick files on removable storage. The `Uri` you get back can be used with a `ContentResolver` and methods like `openInputStream()` and `openOutputStream()`.

Comment: thanks you so much can you edit your post with some code? @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

if you write this permission, you can access the permission. But above marshmallow you have to include how to handle runtime permission.

this is solution link.

https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/

Comment: Thanks but I've did that

Comment: you can check the app's permission. you may deny the permission before.