# Unzip is not working in my application folder in /data in android 6 java

Tags: java, android

i have 2 files in my app folder here

> /data/data/my.application.package/abc.zip   (9KB)
>
> /data/data/my.application.package/xyz.zip   (8MB)

ok now both are in chmod 777 with root permission

now unzipping of both file works fine in all android OS ,EXCEPT Android marshmallow 6.0.1,only 9KB file gets unzipped but not 8MB file

here is logcat any help ?

```
06-17 02:33:30.388: E/ViewRootImpl(17734): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734): uz exp// it is uz function to unzip file
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/my.application.package/xyz.zip: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734):    at my.application.package.MyActivity.uz(MyActivity.java:3709)
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734):    at my.application.package.MyActivity.hus(MyActivity.java:1704)
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734):    at my.application.package.MyActivity$ProgressTask.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:3862)
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734):    at my.application.package.MyActivity$ProgressTask.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:1)
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
06-17 02:33:30.863: E/uz(17734):    ... 12 more
```

i saw xyz.zip which is 8MB file is properly present at right place and unzipping work even in android lollipop but not on marshmallow do not what is wrong with it

not only unzipping i cannot access other files too,i was going to read it to get their crc32 of files and the same error,i have chmod 777 permission to each folder n files inside why this is happening in android 6.0 ?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android) help? (check answer #2)

Comment: hi i am targeting android lollipop so i need not to add permissions from java, PS 10kb file can be unzipped successfully in my app data folder but not 8mb file

Comment: PS aint you think i am unzipping in data partition not in external storage so these permission are not even required ?