# cause = {ErrnoException@5190} "android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

Tags: android, android-testing, permission-denied, android-espresso, aws-device-farm

I am part of the testing team exploring the test recorder using espresso to test our android application.

Planning to run the tests on AWS Device Farm.

Followed their 3 part tutorial @ http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx20RGXMTYT2ZGZ%20/Getting-started-with-Android-testing-on-AWS-Device-Farm-using-Espresso-Part-3

However I am stuck because i am not able to get screenshots for the test.
Have this configuration as part of the androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Am using the source code from the below link to get screenshots

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-sample-app-for-android/tree/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/amazonaws/devicefarm/android/referenceapp/Util

However, I still get permission denied when running the test.

Using emulator to run these tests, 
started with Nexus 5 (API 23) and Nexus 6 (API 23)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to use the [UIAutomator](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator) framework to press `yes` when the permission popup shows up in a testing environment. The following snippet is taken from [this medium post](https://medium.com/exploring-android/handling-android-runtime-permissions-in-ui-tests-981f9dc11a4e#.46qvv3l06), make sure you check it out.

```
private void allowPermissionsIfNeeded()  {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        UiObject allowPermissions = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("Allow"));
        if (allowPermissions.exists()) {
            try {
                allowPermissions.click();
            } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
                Timber.e(e, "There is no permissions dialog to interact with ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

You probably need to ask for permissions at runtime since you are running it on an Android device with API 23.

Check on [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) to see the full documentation on how to do it.

---

Following is a small example that shows how to ask for permissions to read the call log in a device. You would have to change a bit the logic to ask for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` instead of the `READ_CALL_LOG` permission.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivityTAG_";

    private static final int CODE_CALL_LOG = 10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + "Show explanation");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG}, CODE_CALL_LOG);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG}, CODE_CALL_LOG);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + "Permission already granted!");
            printCallLog();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CODE_CALL_LOG: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: Good to go!");
                    printCallLog();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: Bad user");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void printCallLog() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                final long dateDialed = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE));
                final String numberDialed = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
                Log.d(TAG, "Call to number: " + numberDialed + "\t registered at: " + new Date(dateDialed).toString());
            }

            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

[This is the link](https://github.com/Evin1-/w2d5-runtime-permissions) with the full GitHub project.

Comment: Does this show a pop up to grant or deny the action? In my case, accessing the folder is used only for testing, and is going to be run on the device farm. I tried this from this SO question here @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android?rq=1 But that didnt work for me either.

Comment: Yea, you are going to have to simulate clicking on the pop up too, you can use the UI Automator. I edited my answer with a few other suggestions. https://medium.com/exploring-android/handling-android-runtime-permissions-in-ui-tests-981f9dc11a4e#.46qvv3l06