# mp4prasser exception java.io.IOException: open failed:EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mp4parser

when I run this program(I'm use the mp4prasser Library) I receive an exception:

`java.io.IOException: open failed:EACCES (Permission denied)`

but in the Manifest I set the permission:

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

this is the code(API 17):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button mButton;
String Path;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                +File.separator+"AAAATAG"+File.separator+"abcde.mp4";
                startTrim(Path,Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(),50000,100000);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });



}
```

to see the code of the func `startTrim()`:
http://pastebin.com/LDjn3Y7f

Comment: If using  API 23+  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android

Comment: i don't using API 23+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the logcat output to verify, but it is most likely because of this line (see in your pastebin) of `startTrim()`:

```
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

This is attempting to make a destination directory, which the parent of the passed in directory name (`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`) plus a filename you have generated.  No file separator is added.  Since that parent directory is a system controlled directory (and already exists) you won't have permissions to create it.  The same call is made later in `genVideoUsingMp4Parser()`.

The backtrace in the logcat output should point you right to what call was being made which resulted in the `EACCESS` error.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `mkdirs()` call?  Are you creating your own sub-directory to store the altered video?  If so, you need to create a properly formed `File` object with the right name and create a directory with that name; then, write your modified video file there.  Right now it appears to be trying to create a directory which already exists, or a new one at a level above where your app actually has permissions (likely the root filesystem path.)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have placed user permssion at the right place ? Actually I made this mistake once and took a long time to fix.

```
<manifest> 
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

          ...

        <application>
            ...
              <activity> 
                    ...
              </activity

        </application>
</manifest>
```