# how to load image from path into image view?

Tags: android, android-imageview

i storage image path (image from gallery) in SQLite database and now load into image view ... and use this code :

```
File imgFile = new File(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("pic")));
                if (imgFile.exists()) {
                    IMG_USER.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("pic"))));
                } else { Toast.makeText(this, "عکس پیدا نشد", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); }
```

and error :

> E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20161230_224205.jpg (Permission denied)

Comment: Did you allow permission to storage at runtime? https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are need access permission , add this code into android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

or try this

[Exception 'open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)' on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android)