# Programmatically install an apk in Android 7 / api24

Tags: apk, uri, securityexception, android-7.0-nougat, packageinstaller

I am trying to get my app to automatically install an apk.  This works fine for api<24.  But for 24, it is failing.  Android has implemented extra security:

> For apps targeting Android 7.0, the Android framework enforces the StrictMode API policy that prohibits exposing file:// URIs outside your app. If an intent containing a file URI leaves your app, the app fails with a FileUriExposedException exception.

So I tried this:

```
    Uri myuri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
        myuri = Uri.parse("file://"+outapk);
    } else {
        File o = new File(outapk);
        myuri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(con, con.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", o);
    }
    Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(myuri,"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    con.startActivity(promptInstall);
```

but get a fatal exception:

```
com.android.packageinstaller "Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{b42ee8a 6826:com.android.packageinstaller/u0a15} (pid=6826, uid=10015) that is not exported from uid 10066".
```

I have export=true in my manifest.

The problem seems to be that packageinstaller cannot use a content:// uri.

Are there any ways to allow an app to progammatically install an apk with api24?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Are there any ways to allow an app to progammatically install an apk with api24?

Add `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` to your `promptInstall` setup, to grant read access to the content.

> I have export=true in my manifest.

Not on your `FileProvider`, as that would cause your app to crash.

> The problem seems to be that packageinstaller cannot use a content:// uri.

No, the problem is that you did not grant permission to the package installer to read from that `Uri`. Had the package installer been unable to use a `content` scheme, you would have gotten an `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Note, though, that it is only with Android 7.0 that the package installer starts supporting `content`. Earlier versions of Android have to use `file`.

Comment: Awesome.  That did it.  Thanks!

Comment: addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) worked for me too.

Comment: Hey CommonsWare. we have to use if...else for N and lower apis? there is no other way to do that?

Comment: @David: On older devices, use `Uri.fromFile()`. On newer devices (Android 7.0+), use `FileProvider`.

Comment: "I have export=true in my manifest." "Not on your FileProvider, as that would cause your app to crash." Can you explain that? Why would having export=true on the FileProvider cause the app to crash? Do you mean because it should be `exported` instead of `export`?

Comment: @LarsH: No, I mean that, last I checked, `FileProvider` would throw an exception if you tried exporting it (see [these lines](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/b6838fd2d2e834fdd38aab34511d385cb7108f63/core-utils/src/main/java/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.java#L366-L379)).

Answer (score 13):

For Oreo, Add permission in AndroidManifast  (Otherwise it just silently fails)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

now add to you'r Manifest

```
  <provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" 
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

in xml directory add...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="." /></paths>
```

then use these codes where you want.

```
File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("myapp_folder"); 

 File file = new File(directory, "myapp.apk"); // assume refers to "sdcard/myapp_folder/myapp.apk"


    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file); //for Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 24

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {

        fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, fileUri);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
    intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); //dont forget add this line
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: After adding this code, is there something else I need to add? Coz I am getting app not installed. :(

Comment: what is the exactly error you faced on it?

can u go to this intent  that mentioned on top ? =>[ Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, fileUri) ]

and choose cancel or install app? 

if u are inside an activity change context.startActivity(intent) ; to  startActivity(intent);

Comment: Perfect, it works for me!, i needed to add this permission to the manifest.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>

Answer (score 4):

For Oreo,
Add permission in AndroidManifast

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution I have found

```
val newFile = File(dirPath, "$fileNameWithoutExtn.apk")
                        var fileUri = Uri.fromFile(newFile)
                        //use the fileProvider to get the downloaded from sdcard
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                            fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this@SettingAcitivity, applicationContext.packageName + ".provider", newFile)
                         val intent=Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                            intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
                            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                            startActivity(intent)
                        }else{
                            newFile.setReadable(true, false)
                            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                            startActivity(intent)
                        }
```

and write in manifest

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/paths"/>
```

and also set the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

and in xml folder paths will be

```
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but only your code worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add file in `res/xml` -> `provider_paths.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Add this code in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
     <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.provider" <-- change this with your package name
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

run this code for install your app or open

```
    public void installApk(String file) {
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",new File(file));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

simply do the following steps:

1- add the following permission to manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

2- Add provider to manifest (as child as application tag):

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="tatcomputer.ir.libraryapp.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/paths"/>
    </provider>
```

3- Add paths.xml to xml directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<files-path name="files" path="." />
<external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
<external-path name="external_files" path="." />
<cache-path name="cached_files" path="." />
<external-cache-path name="cached_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

4- show install apk page using following code (note that in my case apk is in root of my phone named tmp.apk:

```
       String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

        Uri fileUri24 = FileProvider.getUriForFile(App.applicationContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new File(root + "/tmp.apk"));
        Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(root + "/tmp.apk"));

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24)
            intent.setDataAndType(fileUri24, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        else intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        App.applicationContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Intall Apk automatically

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent1.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" +filename)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case on android 8.0 problem was in

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

More detailed how to get this permission [Exception 'open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)' on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

## Update in 2022

You can't use **internal storage** to install an APK. You have to use **External Storage** instead.

And this is for people looking at how to install step-by-step **APK** on a remote Android device. Also, the tutorial has a **NodeJS Server** implementation.

[image]

[Remote install for Android app using APK](https://medium.com/@ghaithalzein05/remote-upgrade-install-for-android-apk-file-6dbbd75554c9)