# Android open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) when writing file in data/data/package/files

Tags: java, android

I'm getting exception

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /data/data/XX/files/permissions.xml: open
>   failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

when trying to copy file from SD Card to app data location. My code is

```
File copy = new File((getActivity()
                       .getApplicationContext().getFileStreamPath("permissions.xml")
                        .getPath()));
if (!copy.exists()) {
  try {
    copy.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    copy.createNewFile();
  } catch (Exception err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
  }
}
copyFileUsingChannel(xmlFile, copy);
```

method `copyFileUsingChannel` is calling method `copyFileUsingStream` directly. I have both write and read permissions declared in manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="XX">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
...
```

I have no idea why this exception is thrown. I'm creating file from app package. Should it be caused by extending non-app class? Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Interesting fact I realized: File is created but cannot write content into it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception 'open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)' on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you grant runtime permission?
This is a Documentation [Request App Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by renaming file from `permissions.xml` to `prms.xml`. It seems like reserved word of android.