# java/android - Cannot access files on SD card

Tags: java, android, file, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I'm developing an Android App for **Android 8.0** where I need to open/read and delete files from the external storage / SD card.

My problem is, that `File file[] = directory.listFiles()` returns NULL, but there is a file in the directory.

Here is the debugger view from my app:

[image: Debugging App]

As you can see, I'm  getting the filepath as an URI through an **Intent** request (variable `resource`). Currently, the folder `Test` on the SD card is selected.

Then I want to get all the files in this directory, but the function `listFiles()` returns always NULL! But there is 1 image in the folder:

[image: Actual content of the folder]

Interestingly, this code works on Android 4.4, 5.0, 6.0 and 7.0 but not on Android 8!

The permissions are set in Manifest.xml and are requested/checked on each startup:

[image: Requested Permissions]

Note: Android only shows 1 permission request when starting the app, but shouldn't it request 2 permissions?

I hope someone of you can help me solve the problem.

Best regards,
Michael

Comment: What is `resource` in  `resource.getPath()`? Also please paste code as text instead of screenshot.

Comment: Android will show 1 permission by default but will not show the other permission, You need to check and make a permission custom dialog box to grant access to DocumentTree thingy.

Comment: @VicJordan: Sorry, resource is already a Uri. So Umang Burmans' code should look like this: DocumentFile directory = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, resource);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Try to use:

```
DocumentFile directory = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, Uri.parse(resources.getUri()));
```

Instead of:

```
File directory = new File(resources.getPath());
```

### **Also See**

[ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html) solves [the access error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android)

Universal Truth:

### 1. Android 7.0 provides a simplified API to access external storage dirs.

> [Scoped Directory Access](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#scoped_directory_access)
>   In Android 7.0, apps can use new APIs to request access to specific
>   [external storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) directories, including directories on removable media
>   such as SD cards...
>
> For more information, see the [Scoped Directory Access training](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/scoped-directory-access.html).

---

### 2. Android O changes.

> [Starting in Android
>   O](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#imfa), the
>   Storage Access Framework allows [custom documents
>   providers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/create-document-provider.html)
>   to create seekable file descriptors for files residing in a remote
>   data source...
>
> [Permissions](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#rmp),
>   **prior to Android O**, if an app requested a permission at runtime and the permission was granted, the system also incorrectly granted
>   the app the rest of the permissions that belonged to the same
>   permission group, and that were registered in the manifest.
>
> **For apps targeting Android O**, this behavior has been corrected. The app is granted only the permissions it has explicitly requested.
>   However, once the user grants a permission to the app, all subsequent
>   requests for permissions in that permission group are automatically
>   granted.
>
> For example, `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`...

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, now it works! Now I just need to convert a DocumentFile to a normal File. Hint: you're assuming that 'resource' is a String, but it's already a Uri - you can remove 'Uri.parse()'