# eaccess permission denied even with permissions granted

Tags: android

I created a simple test app where I decode a file path into a Bitmap. But even if the permissions are granted it still gives permission denied into the console.
Here's the main activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "DEBUG_";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200118_175558.jpg"));
        }

    }
}
```

And here's the manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.frakm.imagepickertesting">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You don't need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE only grant READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: The problem is that they are both granted and it's still not working,

Comment: Can you try /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200118_175558.jpg? Also check if your filename is ok.

Comment: Tried but still not working :(

Comment: Please check the app's permission (in Settings -> Apps). Does the app have access to storage?

Comment: Does one of the answers to this post answer your question? [Exception 'open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)' on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android)

Comment: The app has read and write permission for storage but still not working. It's strange I know.

Comment: Ok, I found the answer. From android api 29 you can't no more access other apps' files, you have to make a copy of them into your app's cache in order to use them.