# Error while reading text file on Android, open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android

I am trying to access a file in Android, below is the code:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdcard,"sos/xconfig.txt");

if(!file.exists())
   return text.toString();

 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
 String line;

 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      text.append(line);
      text.append('\n');
    }
 br.close();
```

I am also checking for read and write permission like this before reading :

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

        // Requesting the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                new String[] { Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                requestCode);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
```

But I am still getting an error at this line : new FileReader(file).

Error : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/sos/xconfig.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

NOTE: I have already added uses-permission in menifest file.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: How can you try to read a file in that location where under Android Q you could not place it there?

Comment: @blackapps It will be kept by the user when required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are u using Android Q  ?
If that is the case you need to add this attribute in your AndroidManifest file :

```
<manifest ... >
    <!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting Android Q. -->
    <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
     ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Source : [Exception 'open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)' on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android#answer-57804657)

Comment: `That worked.` But not for long. Its no real solution. With Android R this does not work anymore.