# How to make visible the images in the gallery after insertion in the internal storage?

Tags: android, assets, internal-storage

I just inserted some pictures in my internal storage but they aren't visible in the gallery then.

Can someone explain me why?

Here is my code :

```
    File photosFolder = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null),"myPictures");
            photosFolder.mkdirs();
            String[] pictures = null;
            try {
                pictures = assetManager.list("photos");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
            }
            for(String filename : pictures) {
                InputStream in = null;
                OutputStream out = null;
                try {
                    in = assetManager.open("photos/"+filename);
                    File outFile = new File(photosFolder, filename);
                    out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                    copyFile(in, out);
                    in.close();
                    in = null;
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    out = null;
                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getContext(), new String[]{outFile.toString()}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            Log.i("External Storage", "Scanned"+ path +":");
                            Log.i("External Storage", "uri "+uri);
                        }
                    });
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
                }
            }
```

I don't have any result with this, any help ?

Comment: On Android 10+, other apps have no rights to access files in your chosen location. On earlier versions of Android, eventually the `MediaStore` will index them, though you can accelerate the process [by using `MediaScannerConnection`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32789157/115145).

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm still a beginner, and I don't really understand how to implement it with the MediaScanner :(

Comment: Um, well, [the linked-to question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32789157/115145) has sample code in both Java and Kotlin.

Comment: Are they visible in your directory?

Comment: @Danish yes they are

Comment: @CommonsWare `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getContext(),pictures, new String[] {"photos/jpg"}, null);`
I tried this but it's still not working :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
File photosFolder = null;
if(Build.VERSION_CODES.R>Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
    photosFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myPictures");//this will create a seperate directory in your external storage if you are using android 10 device
}
else
{
    photosFolder=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath(),"myPictures");//though depreciated it still works.In android 11 you can create your directory inside public directories using this method.
}
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.mkdir();
}

String[] pictures = null;

try {
    pictures = assetManager.list("photos");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
}
for(String filename : pictures) {
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = assetManager.open("photos/"+filename);
        File outFile = new File(photosFolder, filename);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        copyFile(in, out);
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                new String[] { outFile.toString() }, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
                    }
                }
    }
```

You can check the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I tried this, it returned that on logs : 
**I/External Storage: Scanned/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.data.myApp/files/myPictures/dataset12soleil.jpg:

 I/External Storage: uri null**

Should I need "Permisssions :READ EXTERNAL STORAGE" or just "WRITE EXTERNAL STORAGE" is enough ?

Comment: You have to add both the permission.

Comment: I have both of them :( @Danish

Comment: Actually from android 10 onwards you wont see those picture in your gallery that are present in Android/data/yourpackagename.

Comment: You can check my updated answer.

Comment: **E/tag: Failed to copy asset file: dataset12soleil.jpg
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/myPictures/dataset12soleil.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)**
I have this error on this line : `out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);`
and "getExternalStoragePublicDirectory"  is crossed  for this line `photosFolder=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath(),"myPictures");`

Comment: well finally it's working ! I had to rename my "myPictures" folder to "Pictures". Then I had a permission issue and this post helped me resolve the issue: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android)

Comment: Hi, @Danish. I would like to give an suggestion. Next time onwards, pls add the link in the correct format. Adding it seperately does not make any sense and does not look nicely formatted