# Read an xlsx file from /Documents/: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, permissions, xlsx, fileinputstream

My app has to read an xlsx file from /Documents/. I copied an Excel file (text.xlsx) from PC to the internal storage of the phone: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/test.xlsx.

The code is:

```
    public void loadExcel(View view) {
        verifyStoragePermissions(Settings.this);

        String excelFile =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Documents/text.xlsx" ;
        File file = new File(excelFile);
        Log.d("XXXXX", "excelFile = " + excelFile);
        if (file.exists()) {
            Log.d("XXXXX","The file exists");
        } else {
            Log.d("XXXXX","The file doesn't exist");
        }

        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
            try {
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("XXXXX", "File for found: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The log is:

```
2023-01-07 01:20:05.223 17589-17589/it.linuxp.psswordlist D/XXXXX: excelFile = /storage/emulated/0/Documents/text.xlsx
2023-01-07 01:20:05.224 17589-17589/it.linuxp.psswordlist D/XXXXX: The file exists
2023-01-07 01:20:05.230 17589-17589/it.linuxp.psswordlist E/XXXXX: File for found: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/text.xlsx: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

In Android Manifest I wrote the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The routine

```
verifyStoragePermissions(Settings.this);
```

is taken from [Exception 'open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)' on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android)

So, I cannot understand where is the problem. Please, help me. Thank you.

--------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have access to content in `Documents/` on Android 11+, unless your app was the one that put the content there in the first place.

Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument` and allow the user to choose the document to open. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on that content, using the `Uri` that you get from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`. Try using that `InputStream` with your `new XSSFWorkbook()` call.