# Permission denied while Uploading File in android using multipart retrofit

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit

I am uploading a media file from my mobile gallery
then I get a URI and get a real path and then save it in a list
and on submit button click I get all the paths of the item and upload them one by one.
but not uploading.

```
 private fun getMultiPartFromPath(path: String, partName: String): MultipartBody.Part {
    val file = File(path)
    // create RequestBody instance from file

    // create RequestBody instance from file
    val requestFile: RequestBody = file.asRequestBody("*/*".toMediaTypeOrNull());

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.name, requestFile)
}
```

and here I am uploading this file

```
val response = createNoteRepository.uploadFile(body, length)
```

this exception thrown

```
android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception 'open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)' on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android)

Comment: No @PratikFagadiya I have seen But did not get any lead on this

Comment: If you have a nice uri then do not try to get a path as mostly you have no right to read that path. Well you saw it already. You could have used File.canRead() before even starting the upload. If you have an uri then use the uri.

Comment: Can I get a Uri from real Path, Is it possible to get Uri from the Media store? @blackapps

Comment: ???? You have already an uri you said. Use it!