# Android Studio - How to create application that automatically detects external storage connection

Tags: android, android-studio

Currently I am developing application, which goal is to automatically detect external storage (in this case it's regular USB stick) when connected. Next step is to process operation on files located on this device - I don't have any problems with that. I don't know just where to start, is there any listener that is available from java code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Detecting USB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600896/android-detecting-usb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [USB-Host Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html#discovering-d) from the Android-Developersite.