# Detect connected USB device

Tags: android-studio, connection, usb

I am working on an Android application that has to detect whether a USB converter (for example a USB-C to USB micro male to female converter) is connected to the device being used. From [this](https://pinouts.ru/PortableDevices/micro_usb_pinout.shtml) link I thought this might be possible for USB micro and USB-C, since both have an ID pin for "Mode Detect".

I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600896/android-detecting-usb) post on StackOverflow, which works for detecting whether the device is connected to a PC, but doesn't work for detecting a USB connection from (for example) a converter that is plugged in.

So what I would like to know is the following:

1. Is it possible to detect whether a USB converter has been plugged into the device?
2. If so, how could one detect this programatically?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a *USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED* intent in your manifest. To get your app automatically started when the device is attached you should also specify a *device_filter.xml*

```
<activity ...>
...
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
        android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
</activity>
```

You can find more instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host)