# Debug.isDebuggerConnected, where is package?

Tags: android, debugging

I think this function means that device is connected by USB cable and that device is configured for debugging( debug mode is set on the device).

Java Compiler on Android Studio reports that 'Debug' is undefined. What is the import package?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import android.os.Debug;
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug#isDebuggerConnected()

Comment: Nice! The package in your reply is the one! Many thanks.

Comment: Glad to know it helped.  Please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I disconnected the USB cable from the Samsung 51 device and checked with breakpoint after statement boolean deviceconnected =  Debug.isDebuggerConnected(); Variable deviceconnected came out 'true' but the device was not connected with USB cable. Maybe Debug.isDebuggerConnected() just means debug is ON (connecting to debugging) only.

Comment: From the documentation of isDebuggerConnected() API, it doesn't mention anything about USB connected. If your goal is to check if USB is connected, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600896/android-detecting-usb